# ip function exit code

Tags: linux, documentation, iproute

I use use `ip` by `system("ip link set eth0 up")` in a C program. I know that `system` returns `-1` if it fails and returns what the called function returns(exit). E.g., if eth0 is not exist on the system, it returns `256`. **Where can I find what these numerical values defined for `ip`?**

For example `ifconfig`'s [Return Codes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v54.kill0/ifc.htm):

```
Return Code Description
0    The command completed successfully.
4    The command completed successfully, but a warning condition was detected.
8    The command was not specified correctly.
12    An error was encountered.
16    An unexpected condition was encountered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the return values in the documentation. Failing that, look at the source code.

I think `ip` doesn't do anything fancier than return 0 for success and 255 for failure.

Make sure you've read the documentation of the `system` function properly. Your description is wrong: `system` only returns `-1` if it fails to start the external program, otherwise it returns a value that encodes the process's return code and other information. 256 means that the process returned 1.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [man 8 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) next exit codes of `ip` exists:

> Exit status:
>
> 0 = success
>
> 1 = syntax error
>
> 2 = kernel error